Temporary fix to a torn mesh screen door/window
My large living room sliding screen door has been torn, allowing mosquitos, snakes, and other animals in my house if it is left open. I have no AC in my house and it was designed to use the opening and closing of specific windows and doors with screens to regulate temperature and humidity inside.
I have tried to use tape (doesn’t seem to take because the mesh screen doesn’t allow the tape to adhere to the other piece of tape on the other side of the screen), pieces of paper/cardboard, nothing seems to work and the heatwaves we have been experiencing here in Southern California have been making it so miserable having lost the ability to open the largest sliding door/window in my house.
Any help would be so greatly appreciated and I look forward to any solutions anyone may have, thank you.

I don't think you need a lifehack here. Go to a hardware store and tell them you need to repair a screen door. They will have assorted patches and things which may or may not work depending on how large the hole is, as well as rolls of screen material and the thin rubber strip called spline that holds the screen onto the door. It is not a difficult task to replace a screen and restore your comfort. The store people will show you how, or you can find instructions online. You will spend less than $50, I'm sure.

For a temporary fix glue, staple or tape anything you like to the remnants.
If that doesn't solve it, re-read Kate Gregory's Comment, above.

A rather tedious solution involves another scrap of screen cut to cover the damaged area. A needle and thread is used to interweave the repair screen with the damaged screen. It will take two people, unless you can reach both sides as you work. You don't have to interweave every opening in the screen. Skip about five to ten millimeters between each needle push and keep tension on the thread.
I had very fine nylon fishing line for the repair which held up for more than a decade.

To patch a screen:

Cut a patch of metal screening a about 5 or 10 cm (2 or 4 in) larger than the tear.
Bend, to a right angle, the opposite edges about 1 or 2 cm (1/2 to 1 in), as shown below.



Peel off all the loose wires in the bent areas (beginning as shown in orange), leaving the warp (or weft, depending how you look at it) wires sticking out.
Bend over the other two edges, and peel the wires as above.
Push the patch against the screen so that the loose wires go though through the holes of the screen. Don't worry if a few wires can't go though.
From the other side of the screen, bend over the loose wires, effectively stapling the patch in place.
Apply clear, waterproof glue to the bent-over edges to help prevent the patch from pulling loose.
Alternatively, put in some stitches to hold the patch. Curved upholstery sewing needles, such as these from Walmart, make it easy to sew from one side of the screen.



ok, then i will delete my comment. You may delete yours too.
